# PHP, HTML, MariaDB | PHP gets stuck when connecting

Tags: php, html, database, web, mariadb

I'm trying to get started with PHP and HTML. I now have an index.html and a .php file (both below). When I execute the PHP file the entry appears in the database, when I click submit in the browser it does not. The page is then empty and it probably hangs when the connection is established. Maybe it has something to do with the permissions, but the files already belong to www-data with permissions 755. Maybe someone here knows what to do ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="transmit.php" method="post">
        <label for="username">Benutzername:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br><br>
        <label for="password">Passwort:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
// Verbindung zur Datenbank herstellen
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "---";
$dbname = "test";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO test-table (phone, text, date, time) VALUES ('1234', 'hi', '2001-11-08', '11:30')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: (1) Please check your error logs and let us know what the logs show (2) FYI:  TEXT, DATE and TIME are all keywords in MySQL

Comment: @KenLee which error logs?

Answer (score 2):

So, I used 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. I got the following error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

With another user it worked now, so I changed the root password. Now everything works, even with localhost. Thank you :)